# Microsoft Office Interop outlook dll for office 2007

Tags: dll, download, office-interop

Where can I download the dll for Microsoft office Interof outlook dll for office 2007? Only dll but no exe because I don't have rights on the system to install anything.

For information:

I have Microsoft Office 2007 installed in my system already.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following link to download the Interop.Outlook.dll

http://dllcentral.com/Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.dll/11.0.5530/download/